# Disable warning when trying to declare a global constant that already exists

Tags: php, error-handling

I am currently dealing with a third-party library that defines a global username/password constants in a global namespace. I do not want to modify the library source code at the same time I need to connect with **different** credentials (i.e. more than one set). Therefore, editing the library source code is not the solution. To be honest even without this requirement this is not a good practice to modify the 3rd-party libraries source code as it may lead to unexpected results when updating.

```
define('OSRS_USERNAME', $credentials[self::USERNAMETAG]);
define('OSRS_KEY', $credentials[self::PASSWORDTAG]);

$host = isset($credentials['testmode']) ? self::TESTHOST : self::LIVEHOST;
define('OSRS_HOST', $host);
define('OSRS_SSL_PORT', self::PORT);
//only now we can require the openSRS loader as it otherwise would define other values as contants for username & password
//@ is here to supress warnings about redefining the credentials constants in the 3rd party config file
//this is safe as just including the file shoould not throw if the script does not have any syntax errors
@require_once('OpenSRS/openSRS_loader.php');
```

This, however, still outputs the warning in CLI

Is there any way to suppress those warnings?

Comment: To suppress add `@` usually not a good idea though.

Comment: I tried and it still outputs the warning

Comment: `if (!defined('OSRS_USERNAME')) { define('OSRS_USERNAME', $credentials[self::USERNAMETAG]); }`

Comment: My constants are defined correctly. It is OpenSRS/openSRS_loader.php that is a 3rd party library that tries to redefine those. However, I can not modify the code there

Comment: You can't "undefine" constants, and if you can't/won't modify the library, then you'll have to live with the warnings.

Comment: I totally appreciate that without runkit extension (and it is such a terrible hack) I cannot modify constant as they are by definition not redeclarable. I am looking for a way to suppress the warnings though if it is possible. I'd expect @ to work but it still outputs undesired warnings

Answer (score 0):

This is their config file:
https://github.com/OpenSRS/osrs-toolkit-php/blob/master/opensrs/openSRS_config.php.template

From their documentation you are meant to define these constant in a renamed copy of that.

Check your dist for an existing file called: `openSRS_config.php`